# Mysql - sql query to delete duplicate rows based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with nearly 1 million records - when I wrote a query to see how many of them are duplicates - there are close 90K records that are duplicates - By duplicate I mean records with the same email address - Like for one email address - there could be 10 records.

Sample data

```
ID | Name | Email            | phone
 1 | abc  | abc@gmail.com    | 12345
 2 | def  | def@gmail.com    | 12533
 3 | abc  | abc@gmail.com    | 
 4 | hij  | hij@gmail.com    | 50633   
 5 | abc  | abc@gmail.com    | 12345
 6 | def  | def@gmail.com    |
```

1) ID is the autoincrement primary key of the table

2) If there are two records present like def@gmail.com - I need to keep the record that has the phone and delete the other record

3) Now incase of abc@gmail.com - there are 3 records - the one without phone gets deleted - now out of the remaining two - although both have all data - keep the first one and delete the second

Is it possible to write a delete statement based on a condition or is there an easier way to accomplish this.

A SQLfiddle to play around with - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf8c7

thank much

Comment: is your phone column an empty string when it is empty or is it `NULL`?

Comment: Is this something your need to do repeatedly, to where you would want a single complex SQL query, or something you are doing for one-time data clean-up, such that you could more easily just run a series of SQL queries? Also is there any criteria to determine which phone number to delete (i.e. highest auto-increment value, earliest added by some datetime field, etc.)?

Comment: The default value in table creation is null - so when I run a query like Select * from table where phone is null - I get all records that dont have a phone

Comment: @Mike - I feel its going to be a repeated thing - every time a new file is loaded into this table - I'll have to repeat the procedure to delete the duplicates

Comment: @Mike - No there is no such criteria - in 90% of the cases the phone numbers are the same - so it really doesn't matter

Comment: @Gublooo if you only want only want one record per email address, you might want to add a unique index to the field.  What about the 10% of cases where the phone numbers don't match. You don't care which value is retained?

Comment: @Mike - yes thats the other option I was thinking of - Do this one time clean up then alter the table to mark email as a unique field. Yes as far as phone is concerned - basically keep the record with an earlier enter - by earlier entry I mean - this table has an autoincrement id - so if two records say with id 100 and 200 have the same email but different phones - keep the one with id 100

Comment: If the records have or unique (serial) id (or another PK) , why don't you show that in the question? UPDATE: that's better. Thanks.

Comment: @wildplasser - yes you are right -I completely missed that - I've edited the question to reflect that - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM phoney ph
WHERE ph.zphone IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM phoney ex
        WHERE ex.zname = ph.zname
        AND ex.zemail = ph.zemail
        AND ex.zphone IS NOT NULL
        );

DELETE FROM phoney ph
WHERE ph.zphone IS NOT NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM phoney ex
        WHERE ex.zname = ph.zname
        AND ex.zemail = ph.zemail
        AND ex.id < ph.id
        );

SELECT * FROM phoney;
```

RESULT:

```
DELETE 2
DELETE 1
 id | zname |    zemail     | zphone 
----+-------+---------------+--------
  1 | abc   | abc@gmail.com | 12345
  2 | def   | def@gmail.com | 12533
  4 | hij   | hij@gmail.com | 50633
```

NOTE: You *could* combine the two delete-queries, but that will result in a messy kludge of AND/OR conditions in the WHERE CLAUSE, which is *very* error-prone.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong - but i'm getting this error when I run the first query - Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ph WHERE phone IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test ex WHERE ex.name = ph.name' at line 1

Comment: I created a table test with columns id,name,email,phone

Comment: I added the ph correlation name, maybe mysql relies on that.

Comment: This is the exact query that I'm running - DELETE FROM test ph WHERE phone IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test ex WHERE ex.name = ph.name AND ex.email = ph.email AND ex.phone IS NOT NULL );

Comment: `WHERE ph.phone IS NULL AND EXISTS (...)`. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this - but i'm still getting the same error - this is the query i'm running now - DELETE FROM test ph WHERE ph.phone IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test ex WHERE ex.name = ph.name AND ex.email = ph.email AND ex.phone IS NOT NULL );

Comment: And this is the error - Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ph WHERE ph.phone IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test ex WHERE ex.name = ph.n' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
DELETE b.* FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.name = b.name AND a.id < b.id
```